# Send video from kik bot

Tags: python, video, kik

I am trying to write a simple kik bot to send videos from youtube.
Started with https://github.com/kikinteractive/kik-bot-python-example

Modified it this way:

> ```
>         messages_to_send.append(
>             VideoMessage(
>                 to=message.from_user,
>                 chat_id=message.chat_id,
>                 video_url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHATEVER"
>             ))
> ```

But when try, i get an error like:

> kik.error.KikError: {"message":"Error sending video message:
> text/html; charset=utf-8 is not a supported
> Content-Type","error":"BadRequest"}

Dont know from where is taking "text/html; charset=utf-8" because i ve defined is a **VideoMessage(**

Sorry if it is a silly question, i am noob with kik and python

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `video_url` parameter expects an URL that points to a video file. In the [example from their docs](https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/messaging#video) the URL is `"http://example.kik.com/video.mp4"`, meaning (in my opinion) that it should be a video file. In your example, `"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHATEVER"` would point to an HTML file (i.e. not a video file).

Maybe you'll have to find (a) if YouTube provides a URL that returns a video mimetype (I bet they don't), or (b) use something as [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/) to download the MP4 file, uplaod it somewhere else and use this somewhere-else's URL in yourt code snipet. Or… (c) just send a text message with the YouTube URL : )

Does that make sense?